# Remote access local mysql server

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and Hostinger as a web hosting, how will I get or send data to my local database on ubuntu (Raspberry pi 4)? Can you suggest any solution on how will I do this? thank you!

i tried using localhost.run and other open port website but still can't access my local database from remote.

Comment: You should not access the database directly. Implement some api endpoint to do what you want.

Comment: @EliasSoares I'm new to MYSQL and Laravel, can you enlighten me on API endpoint? Can you give me a reference? I'm very much thankful!

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/building-apis-in-laravel